# Adding JSON from form into hidden input of another form and submit

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms

So basically, i have two forms:

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" name="firstname"/>
<input type="text" name="lastname"/>
</form>

<form id="form2" method="POST" action="http://some.url.com">
<input type="hidden" name="school" value="Random school"/>
<input type="hidden" name="year" value = "Random year"/>
<input type="hidden" name="placeforJSON" id="json">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want to do the next thing:

- When i press submit from form 2, create JSON using form1, put it into "placeforJSON" input name and send form2 to some URL

  I was able to send this request properly, however, im struggling with setting that JSON into input field.

  This is the javascript code (note that im total beginner and this code was taken from internet):

  This is the function that stringifies JSON:

  ```
    $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
     var o = {};
     var a = this.serializeArray();
     $.each(a, function() {
      if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
          if (!o[this.name].push) {
              o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
          }
          o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
      } else {
          o[this.name] = this.value || '';
      }
      });
      return JSON.stringify(o);
    };
  ```

  This is the function that sets "placeforJSON" input when submit is clicked:

  ```
  $(function() {
     $('#form2').submit(function() {
        $('#json').value = $('#form1').serializeObject();
        return false;
     });
  });
  ```

I was hoping that this will add json string before sending form2, however that was not the case.

I also tried to put  `document.getElementById('json').value = $('#form1').serializeObject();` and that didnt help either.

Funny thing is that, for example this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function product(a,b) {
       return a*b;
     }
    document.getElementById('json').value = product(5,3);
 </script>
```

This passed and there was an object placeforJSON = 15 inside request.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This line has a type:
 $('#json').value = $('#form1').serializeObject(); should be
 $('#json').val($('#form1').serializeObject());

Comment: I've tried it now, put it into submit function and sadly its still empty.

Comment: Add this line in the event and see what gets into the console
console.log($('#form1').serializeObject());

Comment: the serialize object reutns the object  how u will set to as a value {"firstname":"gj","lastname":"jnm"}

Comment: Im totally new to javascript but wouldnt "Stringify" mean that it should return it as string value so i can put it into input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what fixed this issue:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form id="form1" oninput="inputFunction()>
<input type="text" name="firstname"/>
<input type="text" name="lastname"/>
</form>

<form id="form2" method="POST" action="http://some.url.com">
<input type="hidden" name="school" value="Random school"/>
<input type="hidden" name="year" value = "Random year"/>
<input type="hidden" name="placeforJSON" id="json">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
function toJSONString(form) {
    var obj = {};
    var elements = form.querySelectorAll( "input, select, textarea" );
    for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var name = element.name;
        var value = element.value;

        if( name ) {
            obj[ name ] = value;
        }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
}

function inputFunction() {
  var form = document.getElementById("form1");
  var json = toJSONString(form);
  document.getElementById('json').value = json;
}
```

On every input change, i create JSON string and set that value to json input.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `$('#json').value = $('#form1').serializeObject();` to `$('#json').val( $('#form1').serializeObject());` should fix this. Please run the attached [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/wzgz3mh4/) and check browser console.

Comment: Console looks fine, however that json is never sent to server because request is being sent before change.

Comment: @Sekula1991 Try removing the return false from the handler function. Returning false from the handler will cancel the submit action.

Comment: Removed it but still, no luck